# h1 heading with equal border at bottom or top

Tags: html, css

I want to create a heading for widgets. The heading will have an equal or parallel bottom border. How its possible? any quick ideas. Attached is what i want to achieve.
[image]

the second heading is the heading that I'm working on now. but i want to look it like above 1st pcture.

[image: this is current]

Hope, you understood that i am looking for paralleled border that is equal to heading and extends the width of heading."

Thank you folks! i got the answer! I'm not going to use span after h1 because it just increases the tag but "display:inline-block;" seems perfect to me.

Comment: add a `padding-bottom` and a `border-bottom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn6s9ga7/1/)

```
h1{
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a `span`.

```css
h1 span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>statistics</span></h1>
```

Comment: Why? Just give the `h1` element some `padding` instead.

Comment: This works great because the h1 still has taken the whole width.

Answer (score 0):

```
H1 {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/e4s8qo5q/

```
<h1>STATISTICS</h1>

h1{
 line-height:50px;
border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this css:

```
    h1{
border-bottom:3px solid black;
padding-bottom: 5px;
width:200px;
}
```